# Can't switch between input languages in MATE

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mate, input-language

Just today I installed MATE over Unity because I needed to fix some compatibility problems with my drivers, so it's very safe to say I'm not the least bit used to it. One thing I notice is that whenever I try to switch between input languages, while I get a notification telling me the language has been changed, nothing is actually different.

TL;DR version:
How do I switch input languages in MATE?

Comment: Without knowing how it's supposed to be done in MATE, it may be useful to know if you are talking about ordinary keyboard layouts or complex methods via e.g. IBus or Fcitx.

Comment: time to try (e.g. from USB stick) new fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Mate ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I actually found it under keyboard settings and not input settings. A bit confusing that way, but oh well. :D